# plot a point within ridgeplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, density-plot

having the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import joypy

sample1 = np.random.normal(5, 10, size = (200, 5))
sample2 = np.random.normal(40, 5, size = (200, 5))
sample3 = np.random.normal(10, 5, size = (200, 5))

b = []

for i in range(0, 3):
        a = "Sample" + "{}".format(i)
        lst = np.repeat(a, 200)
        b.append(lst)
b = np.asarray(b).reshape(600,1)

data_arr = np.vstack((sample1,sample2, sample3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_arr, columns = ["foo", "bar", "qux", "corge", "grault"])

df1.insert(0, column="sampleNo", value = b)
```

I am able to produce the following ridgeplot:

```
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df1, column = ['foo'], by = 'sampleNo', 
                      alpha=0.6,
                      linewidth=.5, 
                      linecolor='w',
                      fade=True)
```

[image]

Now, let's say I have the following vector:

```
 vectors = np.asarray([10, 40, 50])
```

How do I plot each one of those points into the density plots? E.g., on the distribution plot of sample 1, I'd like to have a single point (or line) on 10; sample 2 on 40, etc..

I've tried to use axvline, and I sort of expected this to work, but no luck:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.axvline(vectors(ax))
```

I am not sure if what I want is possible at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had the correct approach.

`axes` holds 4 axis objects, in order: the three stacked plots from top to bottom and the big one where all the other 3 live in. So,

```
for ax, v in zip(axes, vectors):
    ax.axvline(v)
```

`zip()` will only zip up to the shorter iterable, which is `vectors`. So, it will match each point from `vectors` with each axis from the stacked plots.